# Where to install ReportServer

Tags: iis, reportviewer, reportserver

I have 2 servers (IIS & SQL). A web site on the IIS server uses the ReportViewer web control. Should ReportServer be installed on the IIS box or the SQL box. (IIS is in the DMZ)

TIA
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS creates directories in IIS on the [machine it is installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225467%28SQL.80%29.aspx) on. I would recommend installing SSRS on your SQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at your license.  Typically, if you want to install Reporting Services on a server separate from your SQL server, you must purchase another SQL license.  In either case, I would recommend putting your Report Server on the SQL box over your web server.

EDIT:  [Check here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Special-Considerations.aspx#reporting) for the specific licensing requirements.

Comment: That is what I thought and that is where I have it. 

Thanks